# Acessibilidade do site em termos gerais

Tags: debate, qualidade

Eu nunca tinha pensando sobre o assunto antes mas surgiu uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35515/como-usar-sqlstatement-no-sql-server) que demonstra que pessoas com alguma limitação física estão usando o site. Eu acredito que o software do site foi construído para permitir que elas consigam usar bem o site. Mas aí fiquei pensando... e o conteúdo? Será que ele consegue entender bem conteúdo escrito de qualquer jeito?

É só algo a mais para pensar quando encontrar algo que está ruim e for decidir se deve deixar tudo como está ou deve melhorar a postagem para facilitar o entendimento por quem precisa de auxílios extras.

Deixar mais acessível para alguns pode estar deixando menos acessível para outros. Alguns podem fazer alguma coisa para melhorar o que faz no site, só precisa querer. Outros não podem fazer muito, eles só precisam que não criemos dificuldades extras.

Queria só deixar esta informação.

Comment: [Relacionado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6707/75104)

Comment: Para evitar o uso de imagens, utilizo uma [ferramenta externa](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) para criar tabelas de exemplo. Mas creio que deve ter alguma maneira que fique mais acessível para os leitores de acessibilidade lerem isso. Talvez poderia ser criada uma ferramenta nova do SOpt?

Comment: Muito bem apontado

Answer (score 10):

Eu estava procurando sobre esse assunto aqui no site, eu já ia até fazer uma pergunta/sugestão sobre o assunto.

Bom, sou portador de Retinose Pigmentar, e tenho uma leve dificuldade para ler textos em um fundo branco, principalmente quando o texto é de uma cor cinza ou uma cor mais clara.

Seria muito bom se tivesse um menu pra trocar o tema do site, ia facilitar muito minha vida, não só a minha mas de todos que passam por algo parecido, obviamente não sou o único.

procurei bastante no site se já tinha esse tipo de sistema, mas não achei, caso tenha por favor me diga.

abraços.

Comment: Segundo o [SOen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294045/7690982), não há esta ferramenta fornecida pela StackExchange. Mas tem uma extensão de navegador chamada Stylus, para [FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/styl-us/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/pt-br/extensions/details/stylus/). Em que existem vários temas, que podem ser vistos [https://userstyles.org/](https://userstyles.org/)

Comment: O tema no Stylus para stack overflow pode ser encontrado [no GitHub](https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark)

Comment: Consegui alterar o tema com o  https://userstyles.org/ obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Há também a ferramenta [Dark Reader](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader)