# SOpt possui usuários com necessidades especiais?

Tags: debate

Uma pequena conversa no chat agora de manhã me levou a esse questionamento. O debate era sobre adicionar, ou não, descrições às imagens nas perguntas e respostas para servir de auxílio, por exemplo, a deficientes visuais. Acessibilidade é algo muito discutido atualmente e, com isso, levanto a questão aqui:

> O formato de perguntas/respostas do site já satisfazem naturalmente os
>   requisitos de acessibilidade, que permitem um usuário com deficiência
>   navegar sem dificuldades ou há práticas que podemos tomar ao
>   perguntar/responder que tornará isso mais abrangente?

Sei da existência dos atalhos de teclado, disponível nas [configurações de usuário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences), que podem auxiliar a navegação de um usuário do limitações motoras, por exemplo, mas de alguma forma eles auxiliam a navegação com leitores de tela para usuários com limitações visuais?

Também fiquei curioso para saber se, em casos de existir usuários com alguma necessidade especial, identificar quais são e como fazem para navegar no site. Talvez isso fuja do escopo desta pergunta, então como seria um bom modo de identificarmos isso?

Comment: Sabe que eu sempre me pergunto isso. Inclusive sempre tento colocar títulos quando faço uploads de imagens (embora nem sempre consiga descrever bem).

Comment: E a questão do uso da ABNT e sua formalidade no quesito de Acessibilidade para não reinventarmos a roda!

Comment: [O Chrome possui alguns recursos, infelizmente em inglês](https://www.google.com.br/accessibility/for-developers.html#chrome). [Cartilha w3c br](http://www.w3c.br/pub/Materiais/PublicacoesW3C/cartilha-w3cbr-acessibilidade-web-fasciculo-I.html); [WAI Web Accessibility Initiative- (en)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/).Não encontrei nenhuma norma brasileira para acessibilidade na internet (Me ajudem se souberem de algo), somente esta norma que é a mais próxima: Acessibilidade - Comunicação na prestação 
de serviços. [Guia de Referência Acessibilidade Web](http://www.acessibilidadelegal.com/13-guia.php)

Comment: Não deve ser fácil responder isso. Eu sei que tem Microsoft MVP: https://alexandrescostadotcom.wordpress.com/ No meu Face tem foto dele.

Comment: Lembrei que as redes sociais possuem uma tag #acervoacessivel ou #paracegover, seria interessante a criação da mesma? Em que as pessoas descrevem a foto na legenda logo abaixo dela. Nas minhas respostas sempre utilizo muitas imagens pois acho que facilita a compreensão, porém não tinha percebido que isto é inacessível para algumas pessoas.

Comment: Não posso afirmar que existam participando, mas que existem diferentes tipos de programadores e desenvolvedores com ou sem necessidade, que são leitores do site e que chegam via Google/Bing ou outros meios, como midias sociais. Claro que não posso afirmar, mas penso que somos uma referencia atualmente, seria quase impossivel não haver casos de pessoas que leem as postagens através de leitores de tela, mesmo que não participem perguntando ou respondendo.

Comment: @Maniero ele tem profile >>> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15186/magoolation

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. é mesmo, não sabia, já tem uma resposta :)

Comment: @Maniero eu conversei com um rapaz no site em 2015, ele enxergava, mas com dificuldade, não me recordo se eram cores ou profundidade ou outro problema, ele comentou que era um pouco dificil trabalhar com html e css, se eu achar serão 2 profiles pra citar em uma resposta. Apesar de achar que o intuito da pergunta é outro

Comment: A titulo de curiosidade, esta pergunta limitasse a usuários com limitações físicas ou abrange outras limitações, como TDAH, Autismo e Dislexia?

Comment: @gato qualquer. Fiquei bem curioso quanto a isso e estava pensando se dava para fazer algum tipo de enquete para saber.

Answer (score 9):

Pessoas portadoras de deficiência visual não navegam como nós que usamos os olhos, mas a ferramenta citada https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences **não ajudará totalmente** neste tipo de navegação. Então não penso que os sites da Stack Overflow tenham como fornecer ferramentas, o que eles podem fazer seria evitar coisas que poderiam complicar a navegação.

Note que as vezes as ferramentas usadas para navegar vão além des softwares, existem hardwares, como os da empresa [WebAIM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAIM), a deficiência não inclui somente pessoas totalmente incapazes de enxergar, mas também baixa visão e daltonismo.

A própria WebAIM parece fornecer dados/instruções para desenvolvimento software e hardware, ou seja programadores e fabricantes poderiam criar ferramentas, aparentemente a WebAIM é uma empresa sem fins lucrativos, mas não vou falar da empresa, só citei como exemplo.

Um exemplo de quem participa do site é o [@magoolation](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15186/magoolation), o qual o colega @Maniero conhece. Também conheci um outro usuário com "baixa visão" (se encontrar o profile irei cita-lo).

### O que podemos fazer para ajudar?

Muitas coisas só a SO poderia fazer, talvez com o tempo melhorar o uso do [**ARIA**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) no site todo, não só nas postagens. Agora nós como colaboradores creio que no máximo podemos fazer é:

- **NUNCA** usar foto de código, o ideal é postar o código real
- Adicionar descrições as imagens no markdown, por exemplo

  ```
  ![descrição da imagem](<endereço http>)
  ```
- Se possível adicionar descrição aos links:

  ```
  [descrição do link](<endereço http>)
  ```

Eu sei que não é fácil adicionar descrição, por melhor que tente escrever, as vezes a descrição acaba por se inútil para quem mais interessa e realmente não é algo obrigatório, aliais nada é obrigatório, mas isso é o que podemos fazer para ajudar.

Isso não vai só ajudar pessoas portadoras de alguma deficiencia visual, pode ajudar até alguém que esta buscando pelo google ou googleimagens algo e assim a sua resposta e pergunta poderá ser útil para alguém e você pode até conseguir votos com isso, lembre-se, muitas pessoas chegam aqui através dos buscadores.

Comment: Eu acho imprescindível a descrição de imagens. Às vezes fico em dúvida sobre o quanto as devemos descrever. Por exemplo, quando respondo algo sobre autômatos, não sei se devo focar na ideia geral do autômato, do motivo daquela imagem, ou se devo tentar descrever melhoria imagem. Isso também se aplica a fórmulas

Comment: Depois de encontrar esta pergunta passei a me importar mais com a descrição de imagens em minhas perguntas e respostas... confesso nunca ter "atentado" ao uso de "links descritivos". Já a navegação no site concordo que só o SO poderia ajudar, quanto a perguntas e respostas (o bloco de código) não sei se o uso de **ARIA** ajudaria? Há alguma sugestão a respeito?

Comment: @LauroMoraes seria melhor abrir uma pergunta sobre o funcionamento do aria, é que fim de ano eu fico mais lento, mas em janeiro pretendo voltar mais a ativa no site pra falar a respeito disto ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. achei a resposta ótima apenas, gostaria de instigá-lo para a questão sobre **"O que podemos fazer para ajudar?"** no que diz respeito ao uso de **ARIA** no bloco de código. Confesso não fazer ideia se isto seria útil ou se seria ignorado por leitores de tela. Bom fim de ano :)

Answer (score 0):

Acho que pouco pode ser feito a esse respeito. Depende muito do nível de deficiência visual do usuário.

Há um tempo atrás conheci um cidadão que tinha os globos oculares "virados" e esbranquecidos, típico de quem tem algum tipo de deficiência visual, mas que era um aficionado por tecnologia, pois nosso breve encontro foi para tratar de venda e compra de equipamento de computador. Notei que ele de alguma forma me enxergava e que ele conseguia enxergar na tela as informações do seu notebook, talvez, com certa dificuldade (eu não quis entrar nesse mérito).

Acredito que alterar as cores, o tamanho da fonte ou contraste em muito pode favorecer a quem tem algum tipo de deficiência visual em um nível que possa enxergar isso, mas para quem é 100% cego, pouco se pode fazer nesse contexto. A não ser que se fizesse um site totalmente em áudio, o que acho pouco provável e inviável.

Existe software de leitura de tela (pagos, e não são baratos), mas não sei até que ponto eles funcionam ou funcionariam no SOpt.