# Modo noturno (dark mode) no stack overflow em português

Tags: debate

Salve galera!

Tenho uma dúvida que creio ser a dúvida de muitos, já é possível habilitar o Dark Mode para a comunidade do stack overflow em português?

A comunidade stack overflow já possui esse recurso disponível (que está habilitada para minha conta inclusive), mas eu gostaria de estender esse modo de visualização para as demais comunidades da rede das quais participo, como não tive sucesso nessa empreitada, as seguintes dúvidas surgiram:

O recurso Darck Mode já esta liberado para outras comunidades da stack exchange? Quais?
Caso esteja disponível para a comunidade stack overflow em português, como ativa-la?
Caso não esteja disponível para a comunidade stack overflow em português, ha alguma previsão?

Comment: Conforme a pergunta indicada acima, "sem previsão ainda"

Comment: Seria bem legal. :)

Comment: [Relacionado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7414/75104)

Comment: Talvez saia "em breve": https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8380/112052